# Structuring a Keras project

Tags: python, keras, project-structure

I am developing a Keras environment to train DL models, and I am struggling trying to decide the file structure of the project.

Currently it looks like this:

```
.
├── build_model.py
├── ctalearn
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── data_loading.py
│   │   ├── data_processing.py
│   │   ├── image_mapping.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── pixel_pos_files
│   │       ├── FACT_pos.npy
│   │       ├── HESS-II_pos.npy
│   │       ├── HESS-I_pos.npy
│   │       ├── LST_pos.npy
│   │       ├── MSTF_pos.npy
│   │       ├── MSTN_pos.npy
│   │       ├── MSTS_pos.npy
│   │       ├── SST1_pos.npy
│   │       ├── SSTA_pos.npy
│   │       └── SSTC_pos.npy
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── predict.py
│   ├── train.py
│   └── utils.py
├── example_model_schematics.yaml
├── example_train_config.yaml
├── models
│   ├── build_cnn_rnn.py
│   └── cnn_rnn.yml
├── setup.py
└── test.py
```

`train.py` and `predict.py` are the main scripts. They take a path to a model architecture stored in `.yml` format and a configuration file in `.yml` format as well and run the thing.

`data_loading.py` is a factory of `Sequence` objects that are fed to `model.fit_generator()` / a manager to access the real data files (which are located outside the project structure).

The rest of the `data`folder are helper classes for the factory.

The Keras architectures are currently build from a `.yaml` schematic by the script `build_model.py` or by a ad hoc script (for example `build_cnn_rnn.py`) and are stored in `.yml` format, to be loaded by `train.py` or `predict.py` and afterwards compiled and fed a data generator.

Does my structure make sense?

Where should I put `build_model.py`?

Should I have separate `train` and `predict` scripts or mix them together and let the user choose if he want to predict or train via the `config.yml` file?

Should the model path be specified as a command line argument or as an option inside the `config.yaml` file?

Should I remove the `__init__.py` in the inner folder?